# Running a terminal command only in first session

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I want to run a command to display a welcome message in my terminal, but I want it to run only for the first terminal session in a desktop session. I am aware of running commands by adding them to the .bashrc, but those would run in every terminal session and I'm trying to restrict my command only to the first. Does anyone know how this can be done? Thank you.

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10 beta, if that makes difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> first … in a desktop session

So, you need to interact with the desktop session!

Idea: you check for a service that lives under your session. If it's not there, you print your welcome message, then start the service.

So, write a user service, e.g. `welcome-msg.service`, (as in https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd/User#Writing_user_units):

~/.config/systemd/user/welcome-msg.service :

```
[Unit]
Description=Welcome Message one-shot service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/true
```

Then, in your `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
# Check whether the service has been started
if !  systemctl --user is-active --quiet welcome-msg; then
  echo "Welcome!"
  systemctl start welcome-msg
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler versions only using bash:

```bash
# Define the path to the file that will store the last login date
LAST_LOGIN_FILE="$HOME/.last_login"

# Get the current date
CURRENT_DATE=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")

# Read the last login date from the file
LAST_LOGIN=$(cat "$LAST_LOGIN_FILE" 2>/dev/null)

# Check if the current date is different from the last login date
if [[ "$CURRENT_DATE" != "$LAST_LOGIN" ]]; then
    echo "Welcome ${USER}! Today is $(date)."
    echo "$CURRENT_DATE" > "$LAST_LOGIN_FILE"
fi
```